# Interface builder not loading in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios

I am using XCode Version 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3. I created a new view based app (iphone or ipad). After double clicking on the view controller xib and interface builder is not loading up. It seems like it's attempting to open, but nothing.

Have you any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried opening the interface builder app itself and then opening the file? (instead of just double clicking the IB file in Xcode).

Comment: doh! Yeah that worked. I am disappoint.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 3.2.6 has separate IB then the SDK. So, you can try to open the file from the interface builder, or if the problem persists, you can even reinstall the XCode. Maybe it is a "built-in" bug, it happened with me too, many times.